# how to get custom attribute value for related products in product details page

Tags: magento2, catalog, custom-attributes, related-products

I am overriding default **related.phtml** in custom theme
 **Magento_Catalog** but data is not showing properly.If Any One have idea
 please help me.

```
<?php 
if ($currentProduct = $block->getProduct()) {
    $relatedProducts = $currentProduct->getRelatedProducts();
    $blockObj = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Feature');
    if (!empty($relatedProducts)) {


        foreach ($relatedProducts as $relatedProduct) {

                $productId = $relatedProduct->getId();  
                $ProCollection = $blockObj->getProductData($productId);

                $ProductType = $relatedProduct->getData('type_product');
                 //$productType = $relatedProduct->getResource()->getAttribute('type_product')->getFrontend()->getValue($relatedProduct);
                ?>

                <?php 

        }

    }    

}

?>
```

Comment: can you mention layout file for this template ?

Comment: please check the code i mentioned in question